# How to transfer files to EC2 instance in private subnet using a bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, putty

I am trying to transfer files to an EC2 instance that is located in a private subnet using a bastion host. My local machine is running Windows, and I am connecting to the EC2 instance via SSH through the bastion host. I am not sure how to transfer files to the EC2 instance from my local machine using only command line tools and Putty.

Here is what I have tried so far: I  connected to the bastion host via Putty and then tried to transfer files to the EC2 instance using the scp command on my local pc, but I received Connection timed out error.

Can someone please advise me on how to transfer files to the EC2 instance in the private subnet using a bastion host? Do I need to store my private key on the bastion host, or is there a way to transfer files directly from my local machine to the EC2 instance without storing the private key on the bastion host?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Running SCP Through SSH Tunnel | Urban Insight](https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/running-scp-through-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: [ssh - How do I SCP a file through an intermediate server? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/456438/how-do-i-scp-a-file-through-an-intermediate-server)

Comment: [Set Up SSH Port Forwarding in Putty - Ex Libris Knowledge Center](https://knowledge.exlibrisgroup.com/Voyager/Knowledge_Articles/Set_Up_SSH_Port_Forwarding_in_Putty)

Comment: I tried this : scp -i "path_to_bastion_key_file" -J ec2-user@"bastion_public_ip "path_to_file" ec2-user@"private_EC2_ip":"path" but I got this error : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: Is your Edit saying that you managed to successfully accomplish your goal? If so, please add the details as an Answer rather than putting the Answer inside your Question. Or, if you are still experiencing a problem, please let us know the current status.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using the below command and by restricting the key files to chmod 400 I successfully transfer a file from my local pc to my private EC2 instance :

```
scp -i "path/to/private/EC2/key" -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i "path/to/bastion/key" ec2-user@bastion_public_ip -W %h:%p" "path/to/file" ec2-user@ec2_private_ip:path
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `AWS Systems Manager Agent` (SSM Agent). It is preinstalled, by default, on the following Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) for Windows Server:

- Windows Server 2008-2012 R2 AMIs published in November 2016 or later
- Windows Server 2016, 2019, and 2022

Then use a proxy to connect to the EC2 instance:

1. Connect to instance via Remote Desktop or Windows PowerShell
2. Run the following in Powershell

```
$serviceKey = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AmazonSSMAgent"
    $keyInfo = (Get-Item -Path $serviceKey).GetValue("Environment")
    $proxyVariables = @("http_proxy=hostname:port", "https_proxy=hostname:port", "no_proxy=169.254.169.254")

    
    if ($keyInfo -eq $null) {
        New-ItemProperty -Path $serviceKey -Name Environment -Value $proxyVariables -PropertyType MultiString -Force
    } 
    else {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $serviceKey -Name Environment -Value $proxyVariables
    }
    
    Restart-Service AmazonSSMAgent
```

For more info, access AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-proxy.html